# how to align images horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I tried used display: inline-block and other stuff like changing the width but my images only show to be vertical.

```css
.figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

figure.item {
  color: #676767;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
  <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
  <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  <img src="./img/insta.png" />
  <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  <img src="./img/telefone.png" />
  <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  <img src="./img/email.png" />
  <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Right now the images are showing vertically and with text under. And i need the images to be horizontally with text under they.

Comment: one figure per image not all the image inside the same figure

Comment: @Pete - But not multiple figcaptions. And I advise against referencing an 8-year old draft doc

Comment: @Pete here is the last spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element. We can indeed use any content inside it (it need to be flow content: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#flow-content-2) but only one figcaption. Based on his code, I was refering to the *image + figcaption* that need to belong to separate figure which is the main issue here (it was only a comment to this question not in general)

Answer (score 1):

### Using Flex-box

I make a wrap div for every img and text.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
}

.item img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrap{
    width:100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </div>  
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </div>
   <div class="wrap">
    <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  figure.item {
    color: #676767;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  
  .item img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
 

figure {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
      <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
      <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="item">
      <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
      <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="item">
      <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
      <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="item">
      <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
      <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Comment: why did you chose to specify the width on figure and not on figure.item?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your snippet:

- The first line `.figure` is not meant to be a class but a element selector (i.e. `.figure` !== `figure`)
- Block-Elements will be displayed underneath each other by default.

Try to use flex-box. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <figure>
    <img src="./img/facebook.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="./img/insta.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="./img/telefone.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="./img/email.png" />
    <figcaption class="caption">Facebook</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```